# How can I fix Error R10 (Boot timeout) on Gatsby JS?

Tags: node.js, heroku, gatsby

I want to set up Gatsby on Heroku. I have followed the steps from https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/deploying-to-heroku/ and created a Procfile as described here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile, but I'm still getting a timeout error on deploy. It seems like the port is starting to work, but for some reason it stops.

I've tried different lines to put in Procfile, but none of them worked. Currently I have `web: gatsby serve --port $PORT` - this is the last thing that I've tried putting in this file. Also I tried with `web: npm start -- --port $PORT` and other options that can be googled easily.

```
2019-10-24T23:06:52.707649+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-10-24T23:07:49.930330+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-10-24T23:07:49.832843+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2019-10-24T23:07:49.832843+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2019-10-24T23:07:49.910127+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
Disconnected from log stream. There may be events happening that you do not see here! Attempting to reconnect...
2019-10-24T23:06:52.444262+00:00 app[web.1]: ║   To learn more, checkout https://gatsby.dev/telemetry                 ║
2019-10-24T23:06:52.444263+00:00 app[web.1]: ║                                                                        ║
2019-10-24T23:06:52.444264+00:00 app[web.1]: ╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
2019-10-24T23:06:52.445563+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-10-24T23:06:52.707515+00:00 app[web.1]: [2K[1A[2K[Ginfo gatsby serve running at: http://localhost:4563/
2019-10-24T23:06:52.707649+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-10-24T23:07:49.930330+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-10-24T23:07:49.832843+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2019-10-24T23:07:49.832843+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2019-10-24T23:07:49.910127+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
```

Any ideas how can I get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to use `gatsby build` and not `gatsby serve` as the latter is meant for testing locally. `gatsby build` will give you static assets and speed optimizations. Try to remove the Procfile and then Heroku should catch the `build` command in package.json.

Comment: It is weird because now build is succeeded and my `web
gatsby serve --port $PORT` dyno seems to be on, but the application is still not available (https://vectart.herokuapp.com/). I haven't changed anything yet. Thank you for this clarification, I'll follow your advice and let you know if it helps.

Comment: You, sir, are genius, because everything started to work after I deleted the Procfile. Thank you!